# Registry values with & in WiX

Tags: compiler-errors, wix, registry

I'm re-writing an old installer that no longer works on Windows 10 using WiX, and I'm running into a compilation error (candle.exe) with `&` in my registry keys.

The registry value is as follows:

```
<RegistryValue Root='HKCR' Name='' Key='Access.Application.10\shell\New' Type='string' Value='&New'/>
```

I tried escaping it with a backslash just for kicks, but I really don't know where I can go from here.

As you can see in the image below, the registry already has that very value stored, hence the confusion on the error.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some characters in XML have to be represented by character entities. `&` is represented as `&amp;`.